# Тире перед «значило»

Tags: пунктуация, тире, глаголы

Тире ставится перед "значит" между подлежащим и сказуемым. А если глагол стоит в прошедшем времени ("значило"), нужно ли тире?

Comment: Думаю, что необходим пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекста нет, поэтому рассуждаю отвлеченно.

[ЗНАЧИТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
**3. *только 3 л.***: значит, значило (***употр. в зн. связки***). То же, что; всё равно, что. *Простить значит забыть. Забить ещё гол значило выиграть первенство мира.*

Я думаю, что в некоторых случаях тире перед "значило" возможно и вполне оправданно (по аналогии со связкой ["значит"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)).

> Видишь ли, мы оказались в положении потерпевших кораблекрушение, выброшенных на скалистый вулканический берег, поэтому выбирать не приходилось. Остаться **— значило погибнуть,** следовательно, надо было искать способ оттуда выбраться.
>   [А. Васкес-Фигероа. Гароэ](https://books.google.ee/books?id=HGLyBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA236&lpg=PA236&dq=%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%20%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F.&source=bl&ots=aRka75GCoh&sig=ACfU3U1nBndKnfm1BhaDUw21l8NX3xwLWA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj79ZKKkrvpAhWIw6YKHdQKDUAQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%20%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F.&f=false)

*«За Волгой для нас земли нет!» — сказал своим солдатам командующий обороной маршал В. И. Чуйков, имея в виду, что отступить за реку **— значило проиграть.***

> Достигнуть Цнайма прежде французов **— значило получить** большую надежду на спасение армии; дать французам предупредить себя в Цнайме **— значило наверное подвергнуть** всю армию позору, подобному ульмскому, или общей гибели (Л. Толстой. Война и мир).

P. S. Можно еще вот [эту диссертацию](http://www.dslib.net/russkij-jazyk/stanovlenie-razlichnyh-svjazochnyh-komponentov-v-imennom-predlozhenii-v-svjazi-s.html) посмотреть.